# Passing constructor as argument in Flutter

Tags: flutter, constructor, parameter-passing

I have API communication service in my Flutter app with 10+ different services, and 100+ API calls that heed to parse data. In order to reuse code I've decided to create some common parsing code that is going to parse data from API:

```
ApiResponse handleObjectResponse({
    @required http.Response serverResponse,
    @required Function objectConstructor,
}) {
    if (serverResponse.statusCode == 200) {
      dynamic responseObject = objectConstructor(json.decode(serverResponse.body));
      return ApiResponse(responseObject: responseObject);
    } else {
      ApiError error = responseHasError(serverResponse.body);
      return ApiResponse(error: error);
    }
}
```

This way I am able to parse JSON object from API in a reusable way no matter what the Object class is, just by passing constructor function to this method.

When I call this method in any of the Services I've created for fetching data like this:

```
handleObjectResponse(serverResponse: response, objectConstructor: ChartData.fromJson);
```

I get error: `The getter 'fromJson' isn't defined for the class 'ChartData'.
Try importing the library that defines 'fromJson', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'fromJson'.`

Where I think the problem is is in this model class and `factory` statement, but I don't know how to fix it:

```
class ChartData {
  List<ChartDataPoint> points;

  ChartData({
    this.points,
  });

  factory ChartData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    List jsonPoints = json["data"];
    return ChartData(
        points: List.generate(jsonPoints.length,
        (i) => ChartDataPoint.fromJsonArray(jsonPoints[i])));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot pass constructors as functions. You need to create a function what will call the constructor instead:

```
(int a) => Foo(a);
```

Comment: Works perfectly....but what a silly way of doing things....this can't be achieved in any other way with maybe different type of constructors? without keyword factory?

Comment: No, this can't. It used to be a feature but was later removed.

Comment: You can use a static function to create your model and pass that function.

Comment: Note that this will probably change with the arrival of **"Dart Constructor Tear-offs"**, which is currently being implemented. Take a look at [this issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/216).

Answer (score 0):

Just a 2022 update: since 2.15 it's possible by `Class.new`, see the complete issue: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/216.

```
class A {
  final String a;

  const A(this.a);

  @override
  String toString() => 'A($a)';
}

class B {
  final String b;

  const B(this.b);

  @override
  String toString() => 'B($b)';
}

void main() {
  final List<Object Function(String)> constructors = [A.new, B.new];

  for (final Object Function(String) constructor in constructors) {
    final Object instance = constructor('My Constructor Parameter');

    if (instance is A) {
      print(instance.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Note that if you're using named params, both class constructors must have the same param name, otherwise the constructor signatures won't match and then it will generate this static error:

> The element type X can't be assigned to the list type Y.